# I need some help with php mailer (attaching a file)

Tags: php, webforms, sendmail, actionmailer

I have a working php mailer that i love, but it's only missing one thing:
The attachment file.

This is my form:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <form action="http://www.guitara.co.il/wp-content/themes/mguitara/mailEngineThing.php" method="post" id="advfree_new" class="validate" >

    <div class="field">
    <label>שם ומשפחה</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="ישראל ישראלי" class="required min-length_5 namespace" title="אנא בדוק שהזנת נכון שם ושם משפחה‫.‬"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="israel@israeli.com" class="required email" title="אנא הזן כתובת דואר אלקטרוני תקנית‫.‬"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>פלאפון</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id=" phone" placeholder="050-0000000" class="required min-length_10 max-length_11" title="אנא הזן מספר פלאפון ‫(‬בעל 10 ספרות‫).‬"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>ערים בהם השיעורים מועברים</label>
    <input type="text" name="citys" id="citys" placeholder="חיפה, תל-אביב" class="required" title="אנא הזן מיקום השיעורים‫.‬"/>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>מחיר לשיעור</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="100" class="required numeric min-length_2 max-length_4" title="המחיר צריך להכיל שתיים או שלוש ספרות‫.‬" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>תקציר מידע</label>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="23" name="excerpt" id="excerpt" placeholder="שנות נסיון‫,‬ סגנון וכדומה‫...‬" class="required min-length_60 max-length_110" title="התקציר צריך להכיל בין 60 ל‫-‬110 מילים‫.‬">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <label>תוכן העמוד</label>
    <textarea rows="18" cols="50"  name="inputcontent" id="inputcontent" placeholder="על אופי השיעורים‫,‬ מיקום השיעורים‫,‬ עוד עליכם וכדומה‫...‬" class="required min-length_300 max-length_1500" title="התוכן צריך להכיל לפחות 300 אותיות‫.‬">
    </textarea><br/>
    ‪<‬span class="movieMessege"‪>‬
    *אפשר לצרף גם כתובת סרטון YouTube לתיבת התוכן והסרט יופיע בתוך העמוד.
    </span>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div class="field">
    <label>תמונה אישית</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp,image/png,/image/gif" class="required" title="אנא הזן תמונה ‫(‬תמונתך ולא פלייר או כדומה‫).‬"/>
    </div>

    <button name="send" class="btn" value="בחר קובץ">פרסם!</button><br/><br/><br/>

    </form>


    <div id="clear"></div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is my php mailer:

```
<?php

$SendFrom =    "bentalgad@gmail.com";
$SendTo =      "bentalgad@gmail.com";
$SubjectLine = "מורה גיטרה חדש";
$ThanksURL =   "http://www.guitara.co.il/%D7%94%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A1-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%94/";

// Build Message Body from Web Form Input
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value)
   $MsgBody .= "$Field: $Value\n";

$MsgBody = htmlspecialchars($MsgBody, ENT_NOQUOTES);  //make safe

// Send E-Mail and Direct Browser to Confirmation Page
mail($SendTo, $SubjectLine, $MsgBody, "From: $SendFrom");
header("Location: $ThanksURL");

?>
```

I would be very happy if one could help me add the code needed
for that php mailer to attach the file to that mail he is sending.

ThankYouAnyWay!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function XMail( $from, $to, $subj, $text, $filename) { 
    $f         = fopen($filename,"rb"); 
    $un        = strtoupper(uniqid(time())); 
    $head      = "From: $from\n"; 
    $head     .= "To: $to\n"; 
    $head     .= "Subject: $subj\n"; 
    $head     .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n"; 
    $head     .= "Reply-To: $from\n"; 
    $head     .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $head     .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;"; 
    $head     .= "boundary=\"----------".$un."\"\n\n"; 
    $zag       = "------------".$un."\nContent-Type:text/html;\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n"; 
    $zag      .= "------------".$un."\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;"; 
    $zag      .= "name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;"; 
    $zag      .= "filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n\n"; 
    $zag      .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($filename))))."\n"; 

    return @mail("$to", "$subj", $zag, $head);
```

Also look at http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Thank's, But I don't know how to make use of it with my working code...?!

Comment: Just copy paste this function. There syntax error - missing bracket in the end. Then just call this function with proper arguments. This is very easy. Filename is full path to file in your server

Comment: I really don't how, I was just copying and pasting things until it worked, I really don't understand anything that is writen there...